# getLocationInWindow not change after change LayoutParams

Tags: android, location, layoutparams

I have a view like this:

```
<View 
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

I get the global position twice. Before changing the view size and After changing the view size.

CODE:

```
private void getViewPosition(View view){
    int[] firstPosition = new int[2];
    int[] secondPosition = new int[2];
    RelativeLayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();

    view.getLocationInWindow(firstPosition);

    lp.width = 150;
    lp.height = 150;
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);

    view.getLocationInWindow(secondPosition);
    Log.i("FirstLocation", firstPosition[0]);
    Log.i("SecondLocation", secondPosition[0];
}
```

When I see the logs, the location is the same.

What is wrong?

Comment: I think you have to change with `view.setLayoutParams(view);` this line to `view.setLayoutParams(lp);`.

Comment: I edited, i mean view.setLayoutParams(lp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're not waiting for the UI to get updated and for the layout constraints to be implemented.
Try posting it from `Handler` and you'll get your expected results.

```
private void getViewPosition(final View view){
    final int[] firstPosition = new int[2];
    final int[] secondPosition = new int[2];
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams )view.getLayoutParams();

    view.getLocationInWindow(firstPosition);

    lp.width = 150;
    lp.height = 150;
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.getLocationInWindow(secondPosition);
            Log.i("FirstLocation", String.valueOf(firstPosition[0]));
            Log.i("SecondLocation", String.valueOf(secondPosition[0]));
        }
    });
}
```